# ASP gridview: adding two values and validate

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, database-design, gridview, templatefield

I use `GridView` to show/edit data in the database. In the `GridView` there are two columns called `mark1` and `mark2`. What I want to do is when user clicks `update`, the program should check if the values entered at `mark1` and `mark2` sum to 100. If they don't the program should cancel the update and show an error message. How do I do it? I use ASP.NET with VB.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [custom validation control](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145934/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/073102-1.aspx). if you provide some code, i can fix it for you if it doesn't work.